# Setting up Gitosis : push goes okay, but nothing really pushed on the server

Tags: git, ssh, branch, push, gitosis

I'm going to work on a project with a teammate, so we decided to set up a Git server.
We followed this tutorial : http://git-scm.com/book/en/Git-on-the-Server-Gitosis

We created a `gitrepo/` directory locally on my computer, and did a `git init` inside it.
Then, we created a `index.html` file, `git add index.html` and `git commit -m "First commit."`.

We configured the remote server with `git remote add origin git@SERVER:gitrepo.git`, `SERVER` being our server. The `git` user seems to be ok so far, SSH keys too.

Output of `git push origin master` (`SERVER` replaced) :

```
Counting objects: 5, done.
Writing objects: 100% (3/3), 255 bytes | 0 bytes/s, done.
Total 3 (delta 0), reused 0 (delta 0)
To git@SERVER:gitrepo.git
   bf6c7a0..283eb49  master -> master
```

Seems to be okay too, but when I do a `ls /home/git/repositories/gitrepo.git/branches`, there is nothing. I should have a `master`directory, with `index.html` in it, right ?

Something is wrong but I can't figure out what.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As gitosis uses bare repos, the answer is "No". No branches, no files, no-thing wrong.

You can read about bare repos here: http://gitolite.com/concepts/bare.html

You can test that it indeed worked by cloning the remote repo at another location/pull from it.

Comment: Thanks mnagel. We worked this out, and managed to specify our GIT_WORK_TREE in the post-receive hook. It works, but now we would like the files to be under `www-data` permissions. So, in the `post-receive`, we got `GIT_WORK_TREE=/data/apache/www/git sudo -u www-data /usr/bin/git checkout -f`, and `git ALL = (www-data) ALL` in the sudoers file. But we got this error when pushing : `remote: fatal: This operation must be run in a work tree`. Any idea why ?

Comment: probably `sudo` does not carry on the environment (like `GIT_WORK_TREE=/data/apache/www/git`). try to make a script that sets `GIT_WORK_TREE` and the runs `git checkout` and execute this script via `sudo`.

Comment: Yes we did that. But we did a `git pull` of the repo instead of `git checkout` in `hook/post-receive` : http://pastebin.com/q95mySSJ